# Ingress IP with Azure AKS

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I'm implementing [this example](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/complete-example) with `az aks`. I want to use ingress in order to use easily the reverse proxy as in the example with a container redirected to `/tea` and the other to `/coffee` based on the ingress simple rules.

```
  rules:
  - host: cafe.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /tea
        backend:
          serviceName: tea-svc
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /coffee
        backend:
          serviceName: coffee-svc
          servicePort: 80
```

I follow the steps, however, azure wont give an ip address to my ingress as you can see.

```
$ kubectl get ingress
NAME           HOSTS                  ADDRESS   PORTS     AGE
demo-ingress   demo.mydomain.com             80, 443   17h
```

I think azure only give addresses to the loadbalancers. Is there any workaround or solution for this? Can I somehow say `azure` to give an IP to my ingress?

As some additional info, I also tried `helm:

```
helm install stable/nginx-ingress --set controller.publishService.enabled=true
```

However I'm a complete novice and it seems to do nothing.

Comment: Hi @Silgon, As I Understand, Ingressing is part of layer 7 which route the traffic based on path or name. IF you want to get the external IP Address you need to use `type =LoadBlalancer` which is part of layer 3 and 4.

Comment: I played around with simple load balancers with the example in the [azure documentation](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-voting-app-redis/blob/master/azure-vote-all-in-one-redis.yaml), which uses a load balancer. However I do not know how to pass from load balancer to ingress in this case. I could really use an example which I do not find now. I'll look for the information about layers for route traffic, because I do not know about it either.

Comment: Hi, You can expose your ingress controller with `type=loadbalancer`, There is an example which I found on your provided link[ingress-loadbalancer](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/docs/installation.md#42-service-with-the-type-loadbalancer)

Comment: Thanks @SureshVishnoi, I'm playing around with it, I created already the loadbalancer, I'm trying to link it loadbalancer and ingress, I'll keep you posted.

Comment: I did the whole configuration. It seems to work now. Thanks @SureshVishnoi . BTW, it wasn't directly `type=loadbalancer`, because that is for service but not for ingress, it is actually a whole thing to configure.

Comment: Hi, glad that It worked. I can understand that there are a lot of hidden functionalities to discover. I found following article quite comprehensive to understand some of the purpose and functionality perhaps it might help you as well. [Modern LoadBalancing](https://blog.envoyproxy.io/introduction-to-modern-network-load-balancing-and-proxying-a57f6ff80236). have a good read.

Comment: Hi Silgon, As the issue is resolved. you can post the answers with solutions.  we can close the question.

Comment: thanks for the reminder @SureshVishnoi , I'll do it tomorrow, I have a lot of charge today =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took me a while to publish the answer. I wanted to understand a bit more what was happening in the container.

Anyway, the problem with the [implementation](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/complete-example) I was testing, it is that a azure compatible ingress controller has to be installed (that's kind of my best guess, I'm not an expert though). The steps to install the ingress controller are [here](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/docs/installation.md).

All the documents concerned are in the folder [/install](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/install). What I did in the end was a `makefile` containing the following instructions:

```
kubectl apply -f install/common/ns-and-sa.yaml
kubectl apply -f install/common/default-server-secret.yaml
kubectl apply -f install/common/nginx-config.yaml
kubectl apply -f install/rbac/rbac.yaml
kubectl apply -f install/deployment/nginx-ingress.yaml
kubectl apply -f install/daemon-set/nginx-ingress.yaml
kubectl create -f install/service/nodeport.yaml
kubectl apply -f install/service/loadbalancer.yaml
kubectl get svc nginx-ingress --namespace=nginx-ingress
```

It's a bit cumbersome, but as long that it is only one command in my makefile, it's ok.

I hope this helps anyone who encounters the same problem.